# MSTest.exe hanging when Starting Execution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, mstest

I have a blank test case that does a Console.WriteLine() and I'm getting the following errors when I try to run MSTest.exe from the command line (or in Visual Studio 2008)

> [V, 4004, 5, 2012/11/24 22:37:50.382] MSTest.exe: DIA thew in
>   retrieving symbols: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x806D0005): Exception from HRESULT: 0x806D0005    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.Dia2Lib.IDiaDataSource.loadDataForExe(String
>   executable, String searchPath, Object pCallback)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.DiaHelper.GetSymbolsFileName(String
>   imagePath)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I Got the same with :

Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe